# jQuery numeric array comparison

Tags: jquery, arrays, comparison

HTML: `<section class="DataContent"></section>`

Content is appended dynamically on .DataContent through jQuery arrays loop

[see JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3qoxngjd/2/)

How could I make li.rate appear on red if span.ratePercent is < 0, on green if span.ratePercent > 0 and on grey if span.ratePercent == 0?

Trying some functions like: `calculateRate()` in the fiddle but it always end up affecting all li.rate color equally.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use benefit of your loop for appending li elements. Just change your `li` element to:

```
<li class="rate'+[i]+'">
```

And in `calculateRate()` function change the `.rate` class for every if statement:

```
$(".rate"+[i])
```

Complete working code : [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3vkcdtn6/1/)

Now you can have as many as you want `list` objects, and it will loop throught each, and according from their `ratePercent` value it will set properly color of text.